# How can I import opening component at default package?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, mxml

There is a button in opening component(welcome page) and it is invisible at the beginning. When user pass to another component, the button is supposed to be visible. However I cannot reach the `property`.

**What is the way of importing opening component at (default package)?**

this is the button:

```
<s:SWFLoader id="btnRepr" x="1790" y="1008.45" source="@Embed('Components/Starter/Assets/Buttons/ButtonReport.swf')" click="ShowReportPage" visible="false"/>
```

and this is the part I change visible to true:

`btnRepr.visible = true;//Access of undefined property 'btnRepr'`

Comment: Where did you used `btnRepr.visible = true;` ?

Comment: I call it at second component that I have mentioned above. These two lines belongs to two different component/`mxml` file.

Comment: In that case, try : `component_instance.btnRepr.visible = true;`.

Comment: @akmozo I defined an instance of the first component, and made a call like `starter_insta.btnRepr.visible = true;` but throws null object reference. Didn't I suppose to import this first component into the second one where I make changing visibility statement?

Comment: I put an answer, take a look ...

Answer (score 1):

Supposed that in your `SWFComponent` you have your `SWFLoader` :

```
<s:SWFLoader id="btnRepr" source="@Embed('ButtonReport.swf')"  visible="false"/>
```

and you have another component called `BTNComponent` where you have a simple button which will show the SWF loaded in the `SWFComponent`'s instance called `swf_component`, so you can do like this :

```
<s:Button click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

and

```
protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.swf_component.btnRepr.visible = true;
}
```

Of course this is just a very simple and limited example if how you can do what you are looking for, you should improve it according to your specific needs ...

**Edit :**

Supposed that my two components are in `MyComponents` package, then to create their instances I did :

```
import MyComponents.*;

public var swf_component:SWFComponent;              
public var btn_component:BTNComponent;
```

then inside the application's creation complete event handler, for example, I added :

```
swf_component = new SWFComponent();
addElement(swf_component);

btn_component = new BTNComponent();
addElement(btn_component);
```

then when the button inside the `btn_component` is clicked, the SWF inside the swf_component` is set visible.

Hope that can help.

Comment: It doesn't recognise instance in `button_clickHandler` method for some reason. And it works as expected if I directly call like `mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.btnRepr.visible = true;`

Comment: @coner The two instances of your components should be at the same level (for this example) ... In my example, we have SWFComponent's instance and a BTNComponent's one in the top level app. How (where) did you added your components instances ?

Comment: There are three packages under src folder. (default package) is the main package where welcome page(Starter.mxml) located. And all other pages components sits under second package. So I just defined my instance before the _...visible = true;_ line like `var strtr:Starter = new Starter;`. Also tried to define it on top of the functions but same.

Comment: @coner I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I add instances at the very beginning of the code together will all other imports and variables.

Comment: @coner Sorry, really I didn't see the problem. I added a little example in my answer, take a look. Here both instances are added to the application ...

Comment: thanks for the edit but one component(A) is under one package and second component(B) is under another package. Packages are at same level but components not. So as I said before direct reference to button itself from topLevelApplication works(in B) but it is unable to reach instance of the other component(A)-(and I guess it is because it is starter/main/whatever).

Comment: @coner You should know that the level problem is just concerning instances not components in their packages ... We don't care where a component is living but we care about its instance's level to know how to get access to it ... Sorry if I wasn't very clear ...